# SMS sending using GSM Modem/Phone in ASP.Net MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, gsm

I am not so experienced in ASP.Net. 
Can you please give me a sample code or web link from where I can learn how to Send SMS using GSM Modem/Phone with help of third party library (e.g. GSMCom Library) in ASP.Net MVC web application.

I saw the following but unable to send SMS in Web Application:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/e881fb/send-sms-using-gsm-modem-with-c-sharp

Comment: Why are you unable to follow those tutorials?  What is the error?

Comment: could you make it work in a non web app?

Comment: No. Getting invalid settings error: Port 'Com1'does not exist in this system.

Answer (score 0):

please first specify which language you are using with your web application if it is the C# then you should not expect the problems and such a mess as you are expecting!